# Reshaping a numpy array results in TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm following a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1ZrOs9s2QA&feature=youtu.be), the code can be found here: https://github.com/murtazahassan/Digits-Classification/blob/master/OCR_CNN_Trainning.py

But when I try to run the code below, I get the error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

```
x_train = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_train)))
x_test = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_test)))
x_validation = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_validation)))

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train[0], x_train[1], x_train[2], 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test[0], x_test[1], x_test[2], 1)
x_validation = x_validation.reshape(x_validation[0], x_validation[1], x_validation[2], 1)
```

I found this ([TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index , while trying kfold cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55780743/typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-scalar-index-while)) and this ([TypeError when indexing a list with a NumPy array: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638332/typeerror-when-indexing-a-list-with-a-numpy-array-only-integer-scalar-arrays-ca)), but it did not help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With numpy, what do you get if you do `name.dtype` for all the arrays?

Comment: @duckboycool I get float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing values to `reshape` that are not of type `int`:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train[0], x_train[1], x_train[2], 1)
```

Here, for example, `x_train[0]` need to be of type int (and so the rest). If you meant to use their shape instead of their values, use:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1)
```

Otherwise, you have two options:

1. If you know values in `x_train`, `x_test` and `x_validation` are integers, set their dtype to `int` (and make sure it remains the same during ML operations:

   ```
   x_train = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_train)), dtype=np.int)
   x_test = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_test)), dtype=np.int)
   x_validation = np.array(list(map(preprocess, x_validation)), dtype=np.int)
   ```
2. If you need them to be `float` but want to call them as `int`, use:

   ```
   x_train = x_train.reshape(int(x_train[0]), int(x_train[1]), int(x_train[2]), 1)
   ```